# Understanding a definition for vector-spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, transformation

Let $V$, a finite dimensional vector space, and $L$, a subspace of $V$. Let $T:V^*\rightarrow L^*$ defined as: $T(\varphi)(x)=\varphi(x)$ for all $\varphi \in V^*$. Prove $T$ is onto.

Well, I'm struggling with understanding what are $L^*, V^*$ with relation to $L, V$.

Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: I assume you mean only *finite-dimensional*, not necessarily *finite*?

Comment: Indeed, thank you. Corrected that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V^*$ is the dual space to $V$, that is the vector sapce of all linear maps $V\to k$ to the ground field (this is a vector space via pointwise addition and mutlpplication with scalars). So if $\phi\in V^*$ is a linear map $V\to k$, $v\mapsto \phi(v)$, then $T(\phi)$ is the linear map $L\to k$ given by $x\mapsto \phi(x)$, i.e. the restriction to $L$.

*Remark:* Unless you have issues with the Axiom of Choice, the condition that $V$ be finite dimensional can be dropped.

Comment: Oh, so it's a familiar notation I'm not aware of. Thanks!

Comment: I bet it git introduced just a few paragraphs before the problem statement :)

Comment: Well, actually it's not part of our syllabus. Some teachers do teach dual-spaces though. I bet I'll be introduced with that material at Linear Algebra II.